# References to saved date display nothing until the table is changed

Tags: filemaker

I have a date saved in my table and want to display the date written in "dd.mm.yy" format. For this I use a *"drop-down calendar"*. I also tried the text-tool by typing `<<Semester_DSH::Datum schriftliche Teilprüfung>>` in it, but the behaviour is exactly the same.

The problem is that, somehow, the date is not shown and seems empty (not a default date, just nothingness). My predecessor set this up and was aware of it, but not able to fix this issue. He implemented a *"fix"-button* which temporarily **changes the date in the database and immediatly sets it back to its original** value. This **workaround** fixes all references to this table, for the whole session. It is apparently not important which date is changed.

**Why does the table need to be refreshed for the date to show up, and how can I make the date references work immediatly without having to press a button?**

Comment: I am afraid it's not clear what your question is. A drop-down calendar is used to **enter** a date value into a date field, not to display it. If the date field already contains a date, the drop-down calendar will initially show with that date selected; otherwise it will default to the current date.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I even tried the text-tool (added it to the question)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what this is about. Perhaps it would be best to move this to one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform, where you can have  a discussion, incl. exchange of files if necessary. SO is purely a Q&A site.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I reread it and agree, it wasn't clear. I changed my question to be about the actual issue. (The not-referencable date, not the displaying) Hopefully it fits now?

Comment: I repeat the suggestion. There are too many factors at play here, and this is not a good format to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve got a feeling your date field is set as a global field which is why it starts empty. Also in a drop down calendar you can format the date however you want but when using text and a merge field it is always formatted however it was entered.

Comment: "*when using text and a merge field it is always formatted however it was entered.*" You **can** format dates in merged fields too. The only limitation is that all dates merged in a text block will be formatted the same. In any case, I don't think the format matters when the field "seems empty".

Comment: How do you do that? Rearrange the order that the month day year appear?

Comment: So if this: `<<Semester_DSH::Datum schriftliche Teilprüfung>>` was typed into the text block, where are the options to format the date?

Comment: The same place where you format a date field: Inspector > Data > Data Formatting > Date.

Comment: Never knew that